# Can I use Business Objects XI R2 with an Oracle 12c datasource?

Tags: oracle12c, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

We are upgrading from 11g to 12c and I was curious if Business Objects XI R2 will be compatible and if anyone has had any experience/recommendations in doing so.

Comment: If you're currently using an 11g Oracle client on your BO server, you can probably continue to use that client to connect to 12c.

Comment: thanks.  Have you been able to do so in the past?  While nothing official I ran across something that said I would have issues with the CMS database being on 12c

Comment: I haven't used that specific configuration, so I can't say for sure.  Compatibility of BO to Oracle is usually stated in terms of the middleware client rather than the database server. So there are two questions -- compatibility of XIr2 to the 11g client, and the 11g client to the 12c database.  You're already using the 11g client, so you're good there. And the 11g client can connect to a 12c server. Unless you find something that definitely says it won't work, I think it's worth a try.  No guarantees, of course....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if BusinessObjects XI R2 is compatible with Oracle 12c.

Even though, I'd like to share a personal experience. Some days ago we upgraded our database from **Oracle 11gR2** to **Orale 12c** and BusinessObjects works correctly.

Environment :

- BusinessObjects **4.1 SP6**
- Windows 2008 R2

Here are the steps I followed :

1. Dump CMS schema in Oracle (in my case, the CMS schema was called "BOCMS")

`expdp SYSTEM/<password>@<database> directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR parallel=8 dumpfile=BOCMS.dmp logfile=BOCMS.log SCHEMAS=BOCMS exclude=INDEX_STATISTICS exclude=TABLE_STATISTICS`

2. Upgrade Oracle from 11gR2 to 12c
3. Create (or migrate) your database
4. Install 12c Oracle Clients (32b and 64b)
5. Test connection to your database (I used `sqlplus` command)
6. Import the dump created in step 1

`impdp SYSTEM/<password>@<database> directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=BOCMS.dmp table_exists_action=replace logfile=BOCMS.log`

Be sure your CMS schema has the same password you set on BusinessObjects when using it with Oracle 11gR2.

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: thank you Ivan.  Appreciate detail on your experiences